# Scala shell. Declare same varibale name multiple times

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

In Scala Shell, I can declare same variable multiple times and I am not getting any error/warning

For Example

```
scala> val a = 1
a : Int = 1
scala> val a = 2
a : Int = 2
scala> val a = 1
a : Int = 1
scala> lazy val a = 1
a : Int = <lazy>
```

Here variable name "**a**" is declared multiple times with `var`, `val` and `lazy val`

So I would like to know

1. How scala complier took this? eg: `val a = 1` and `var a = 2` which is higher precedence?
2. Why Scala shell is accepting while declaring the same name of variable multiple time?
3. How do i know whether declared variable is mutable or immutable since the same variable name is declared as `var` and `val`?

Note: In IntelliJ, Able to declare same variable with multiple time and I don't see error but while accessing IDE shows error as "Can not resolve varibale" so what is the use the declaring same variable multiple times?

Comment: A REPL usually allows this for convenience with the general idea that, when coding interactively, especially by executing statements a few at a time, redefinitions of an identifier should overwrite previous ones.

Comment: Consider each prompt to open a new scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the repl, there is often experimenting and prototyping taking place, and redefining a val is most often not by mistake, but intentional.

Precedence is taken what you typed finally successful.

```
scala> val a: Int = 7
a: Int = 7

scala> val a: Int = "foo"
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("foo")
 required: Int
       val a: Int = "foo"
                    ^

scala> a
res7: Int = 7
```

If you aren't sure, whether a name  is already in use, you may just type the name, like `a` in my case, and get a feedback. For undeclared values, you get:

```
scala> b
<console>:13: error: not found: value b
       b
       ^
```

But if you paste a block of code with the `:pas` technique, multiple names in conflict won't work and the whole block is discarded.